# PHP, PDO & MySQL - HTML input-type Date to MySql DATE

Tags: php, html, mysql, date, pdo

I have checked the long list of questions, which seem to pertain to solve the issue of not being able to convert a date produce in HTML to a MySQL compliant DATE format (Please note: DATE not DATETIME).

Using the following snippet of HTML, I'm forming an input via POST (Please note: There are other inputs on the form, this is just a breakdown to make it easier to model).

```
<!-- Language: HTML -->
<form method="post" action="php/editLoan.php">
    <input type="date" name="dateOfLoan"/>
</form>
```

---

When the submit button is pressed, the information is POSTed to the referenced PHP file. Here, there is a lot going on, so I will just include what happens to the date.

```
// Language: PHP (7.1), which is the latest supported version for my host.

$dateOfLoan = $_POST["dateOfLoan"];  // Grabs the date of the loan from the postman.

$sqlDate = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($dateOfLoan));  // Converts the format.

$dbh = new PDO($this->connString, $username, $password);
$query = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO theTable (theDateField) VALUES ($sqlDate)");
$query->execute();
```

---

Based on what I've seen from looking for answers, this should work. But, when I head over to phpMyAdmin (4.6.6), the column "theDateField" shows the following entries.

```
c:theDateField
0000-00-00
0000-00-00
0000-00-00
0000-00-00
```

---

I'm not quite sure where I'm going wrong and some guidance would be really appreciated! Thank you very much for your help! :D

Comment: Are you sure posted date has no spaces or any other special character

Comment: Have you tried to print $dateOfLoan variable? What it is printing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use single quote on value-

```
$query = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO theTable (theDateField) VALUES ('$sqlDate')");
```

Comment: Aren't you a star? Thank you so much <3

Answer (score 3):

Use a proper parameter in the prepared statement, instead of variable substitution.

```
$query = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO theTable (theDateField) VALUES (:date)");
$query->bindParam(':date', $sqlDate);
$query->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

This may solve your problem:

```
$dateOfLoan = $_POST["dateOfLoan"];
$query = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO theTable (theDateField) VALUES (STR_TO_DATE('$dateOfLoan', '%d/%m/%Y'))");
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.